# XCTestCase with Pure Swift class

Tags: xcode, swift

### Does XCTest work with Pure Swift?

It appears that you can only use XCTest with swift classes that inherit from NSObject.  Is there a method for testing PURE SWIFT classes with the built in test feature of Xcode?  And if not what is a good framework.

---

**Xcode Project Name:** Locations

**Class Name:** FileReader

```
public class FileReader {
}

public class FileReader2 : NSObject {
}
```

**Test Class:** FileReaderTests

[image]

So obviously it would appear that XCTestCase wants to reference `: NSObject` classes.  Is there a way to test with a pure swift class that doesn't inherit from `NSObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select FileReader.swift in navigator, in File Inspector->Target Membership check test target to include file in unit test target.

[image]

Comment: THANKS! I added a picture to your answer btw

Comment: Does this also mean I don't need to declare my classes Public to test them as well?